# Integral of Logarithm and Gaussian functions

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} dx \: \frac{1}{\sigma_i} \exp \left( -\frac{(x-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2} \right) \log_2\left[1+\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_j} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-\mu_j)^2}{2\sigma_j^2} \right) \exp\left( \frac{(x-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2} \right) \right] $$

I can't seem to find it in neither the Bronstein nor Gradshteyn. I also tried to solve it symbolically with Maple but it took too long to find a solution.

Every suggestion or idea is welcome, for definite or indefinite solutions of the integral :)

Comment: Depending on the relative magnitude of $\sigma_i, \sigma_j$ you could try the usual Taylor expansion of the logarithm. Not sure if a sign is missing in your final Gaussian however.

Comment: No, there is no minus sign missing, the original integral was a bit more complex and I could simplify it to this.
And I think a Taylor expansion wouldn't be of any use, because I am trying to prove a relation, but thanks for the tip, maybe I can find a useful inequality on the way :)

Comment: What's wrong with a numerical evaluation?

Comment: I want to find the relation between this expression and the Bhattacharyya coefficient of the two Gaussians